# Mongoose - How to populate only the first element in a nested array of every object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I am trying to create a Chat App in NodeJS, Mongoose and React Native and I want to show to the user the last message of every conversation.

I have an array of messages in my Conversation Schema as following:

```
const ConversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    {...}
    messages: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Message'
        }
    ]
    {...}
})
```

I wonder if anyone can help me to be able to only populate the first message of every Conversation so the response will be:

```
conversations: [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId(...)
        "messages": [
             "text": "Last message"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId(...)
        "messages": [
             "text": "Last message"
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I am currently using the `populate` function of mongoose but the problem is that if only populates the first conversation:

```
Conversation.find().populate(query).exec((err, conversations => {
    {...}
})

const query = {
    {
        path: "messages",
        options: {
            limit: 1,
            sort: { _id: -1 }
        }
    }

}
```

Note: If I do not specify the `limit: 1` and `sort: { _id: -1 }` it correctly populates all elements of the array but that's not what I am looking for.

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [perDocumentLimit](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#limit-vs-perDocumentLimit) than `Limit`

> If you need the correct limit, you should use the perDocumentLimit option (new in Mongoose 5.9.0). Just keep in mind that populate() will execute a separate query for each story, which may cause populate() to be slowe

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much